# Need to solve x^4≡4(mod19)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need some help in trying to solve :
$$x^4\equiv 4\pmod{19}.$$
I have the solution $6$ and $13$ but I'm not clear how it was solved.

Comment: i have also got this solutions

Comment: Yes. $x^4-4$ factors as $(x-6)(x+6)(x^2-2)$, the latter factor is irreducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{F}_{19}$ is a field the solutions of 
$$ x^4\equiv 4\pmod{19} $$
are simply given by the solutions of $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{19}$ plus the solutions of $x^2\equiv -2\pmod{19}$. Since $19$ is a prime $\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ we have that $-2$ is a quadratic residue and $2$ is a quadratic non-residue, so only $x^2\equiv -2\pmod{19}$ is solvable, and the solutions are given by $\color{red}{x\equiv \pm 6\pmod{19}}$.